# Radio buttons issue Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I got a `ButtonGroup` with 2 `RadioButton` inside. When I run the Simulator it looks fine, but when running on Device it gets a weird text offset like example:

**in Simulator(/iphone3gs.skin):**

[image: in Simulator]

**on Android Device:**

[image: on Android Device]

It happens in the following themes: Business, FlatOrange, FlatBlue and FlatRed. Didn't test on Mapper yet because of a bug as I reported previously where Mapper theme is a blank theme instead when editing the theme.res, the only way to get Mapper fine is by the wizard when creating a project. So how to fix that weird text offset also will Mapper theme be fixed?

Comment: Which device and which simulator skin? Did you wrap this in a `ComponentGroup`? Screenshots would help

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Edited my question, Android Device, /iphone3gs.skin, I didn't wrap in a `ComponentGroup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is center alignment which is defined in the theme itself for `RadioButton`.

[image]

This isn't visible in the simulator because for some reason opposite side only works on the simulator and not on the device. Make sure your skin files are up to date.

Comment: Thanks Shai, by the way why on Android Device all my buttons are in uppercase?

Comment: Never mind I forgot to remove includeNativeBool that's why.

Comment: Don't remove includeNativeBool! It's a bad idea to do that. See the caps discussion here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/factional-padding-margin-rounded-border-ripple-caps-google-connect.html